# Copy Record From One Form to Another

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a list of records with location information.  Each record starts with a checkbox.  I would like the user to be able to select multiple records they are interested in by clicking the checkboxes and then click a submit button on the bottom to then pass the selections through and copy them as new records to another form.  How would I do this in VBA?

First, the data for my main form is fed in through a table.  I created a new field and assigned it as a Boolean data type to show a checkbox icon next to each record in the form.  Everything is checked on by default which is the first issue.  How do I get all records to be unchecked by default?

Second, assuming I figure out the checkbox issue, how do I then have Access pull the desired records into a new form via a coded submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the checkbox as a boolean table field, you can update the records and then when the user clicks the command button, either pass the SQL clause "where fieldY =true" as a parameter like "DoCmd.OpenForm "SecondForm", acNormal, , , , , "where fieldY =true". Then in the form open event, use Me.OpenArgs to get the clause to filter the records.

Or just have the second form record source include the clause "where fieldY =true" so it always opens with just those records.

Comment: I really like your last idea of just having the second form look for the records with checks.

I'll have to play around with establishing the checkbox field to have it editable.

Comment: I'm now having an issue where I cannot set the checkboxes to be empty by default.  I've tried setting the Default Value in Design Mode to False, Off etc and they still appear checked.

Comment: On the first form's form_load event run an update query that sets the checkbox field value to false.